# Highlight Row on Gridview LinkButton Clicked with Confirmation Alert ASP.Net

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, gridview

I have Delete button and confirm alert is working fine. But I want to color the BackColor of selected row prior to show alert. Its working fine and showing BackColor to Grey for View button because there is not alert for View button. But it does not show BackColor changed for Delete button as it alert first and on Yes, it goes to RowCommand event.

How to change backcolor prior alerting for delete message?

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Option">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:LinkButton ID="btnEdit" CommandName="editRecord" Width="14px" Height="14px" aria-label="Left Align"
            CommandArgument='<%# Eval("DeptID") + "," + Eval("DeptName")%>' CssClass="" runat="server">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil" style="vertical-align:top;"></span>
        </asp:LinkButton>

        <asp:LinkButton ID="btnDelete" CommandName="deleteRecord" Width="14px" Height="14px" 
            OnClientClick="javascript:return confirm('Are you sure you want to Delete highlighted row?');"
            CommandArgument='<%# Eval("DeptID") + "," + Eval("DeptName")%>' CssClass="" runat="server">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        </asp:LinkButton>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <ItemStyle CssClass="col-md-1 col-sm-1 col-xs-1 grid-label-text-align grid-height-10"></ItemStyle>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

--Code Behind

```
protected void grdDept_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    lblMessage.Visible = false;

    GridViewRow gvr = (GridViewRow)(((LinkButton)e.CommandSource).NamingContainer);
    int RowIndex = gvr.RowIndex;
    grdDept.Rows[RowIndex].BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.LightGray; 

    if (e.CommandName == "editRecord")
    {
        string[] commandArgs = e.CommandArgument.ToString().Split(new char[] { ',' });
        string deptID = commandArgs[0];
        string deptName = commandArgs[1];

        hfDeptID.Value = deptID;
        txtDeptName.Text = deptName;
        //btnAdd.Text = "Update";
        panel1.Visible = true;
        lblMessage.Visible = false;
    }
    else if (e.CommandName == "deleteRecord")
    {
        string[] commandArgs = e.CommandArgument.ToString().Split(new char[] { ',' });
        string deptID = commandArgs[0];

        if (ChildRecordExist(int.Parse(deptID)) == false)
        {
            DepartmentClass dept = new DepartmentClass();
            dept.DeptID = int.Parse(deptID);

            TransactionOptions options = new TransactionOptions();
            options.IsolationLevel = System.Transactions.IsolationLevel.ReadCommitted;
            options.Timeout = new TimeSpan(0, 15, 0);

            using (TransactionScope tran = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.Required, options))
            {
                if (deptID != "")
                {
                    if (dept.Delete() == true)
                    {
                        tran.Complete();
                        panel1.Visible = false;
                        lblMessage.Visible = false;
                    }
                }
            }
            LoadAllRecords("");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Not clear with what you are looking for exactly. I assume that you want to highlight row when user click on row, correct?

Comment: Thanks for reply Piyush, I want to highlight row when User press Delete button. and on pressing Delete button, it give alert "Are you sure to delete highlighted row?" if user press Yes, then delete record otherwise No.

Comment: Ok, so I think as per your code, you just get alert box, not row highlighted, correct?

Comment: Yes because alert at client side runs first and if I press Yes, then it go to RowCommand event where I am setting backcolor to grey.

Comment: Can you try this, http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/24475/Change-the-GridView-row-color-on-click-without-pos

Comment: This example is good but not working with me. I put alert in javascript function that working on row click but color not changing

Comment: Can you please update post with latest code?

Answer (score 0):

You must set a class name for delete buttons for example `class="delete"`
Now add this jquery:

```
$('.delete').click(function(){
    $('td').css('background-color', 'white') //change back all tds to their original background.
    $(this).closest('tr').css('background-color', 'red');
    return confirm('are you sure to delete?');
 });
```

and adding this make better look for selected row:

```
tr.selected{border-collapse: collapse;}
```

Answer (score -1):

Use an `onmousedown` event to highlight the row to be deleted, followed by the `onclick` event to do the actual deletion.